# android navigation components passing data between fragment directions

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, fragment

Here is my navigation file

```
<navigation
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/fragmentA">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentA"
        android:name="com.example.fragmentdatapassings.FragmentA"
        android:label="Fragment A">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_fragmentA_to_fragnentB"
            app:destination="@+id/fragmentB" />
        <argument
        android:name="x"
        app:argType="integer" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentB"
        android:name="com.example.fragmentdatapassings.FragmentB"
        android:label="FragmentB">
    </fragment>

</navigation>
```

Here is the code for fragment directions data passing.

```
val x : Int = 10
val action = FragmentADirections.actionFragmentAToFragnentB(x)
Navigation.findNavController(requireView()).navigate(action)
```

the above 2nd line shows error

> Too many arguments for public open fun

When I hover the mouse over the error, it shows add parameter x, I do click it and it does
add the parameter x in FragmentADirections. But after building the app again it shows error
again.

Comment: You can use safe Args to pass value between fragment in navigation components. Check this codelab: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-start-external-activity/index.html#3

Comment: what I have done is just the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<argument>` should be in fragment you want to receive not from which you are sending

If you want to pass data from fragment **A** to **B**

```
  <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentB"
        android:name="com.example.fragmentdatapassings.FragmentB"
        android:label="FragmentB">
        <argument
        android:name="x"
        app:argType="integer" />
    </fragment>
```

and delete argument from fragment **A** and it should be fine as it is